# Hibernate saveOrUpdate method is trying to update when it actually supposed to do an insert in JBoss EA7. Same code works fine in WebSphere

Tags: spring, hibernate, jboss

Hibernate **saveOrUpdate** method is always trying to update **[throws exception]** when it actually supposed to do an insert in JBoss EA7 Server. The same code works perfrectly in WebSphere Server.
**Server:** JBoss EA7
**Hibernate**: 3.2
Spring HibernateTemplate
**Database:** Microsfot SQL
**Error Message:** Could not synchronize database state with session: org.hibernate.StaleStateException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1
**Reason**: In JBoss server, the code always trying to perform update, which causes the above mentioned exception.  **Can somebody help me to tweak the configurations to make it working for JBoss**. This code(insert/update using the same code) works perfectly in Websphere(insert/update using the same code).**Thanks in advance.**

```
    Entity Class:
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "TAB_SAMPLE", schema = "MYSCHEMA", catalog = "MYSCHEMA", uniqueConstraints = {})
    public class TestEntity extends BaseObject<Long> {
     private static final long serialVersionUID = -12334423232L;
     /** default constructor */
     public TestEntity() {
     }
     /** minimal constructor */
     public TestEntity(Long testId) {
       super.setId(testId);
     }
     /** full constructor */
     public TestEntity(Long testId, args......) {
       super.setId(testId);
       .............
     }
     @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
      @Column(name = "MASTER_ID", unique = true, nullable = false,   insertable = true, updatable = true)
     public Long getId() {
        return super.getPersistentId();
     }
    }
    //class which sets the Id
    @MappedSuperclass
    public abstract class BaseObject<PK> implements Serializable {  
     private PK id;

     /**
      * GETTER must be defined in the subclass so that JPA attributes can be annotated there
      * public PK getId();
      */
       public final void setId(PK id) {
         this.id = id;
        }                             

       @Override
       public abstract String toString();

       @Override
       public abstract boolean equals(Object o);

       @Override
        public abstract int hashCode();

       @Transient
        protected PK getPersistentId() {
          return this.id;
        }
    }

Code snippet which invokes the saveOrUpdate method

  public T save(T entity) {// I did debug, and found the id=0 at the entity class.
      super.getHibernateTemplate().saveOrUpdate(entity);
      getHibernateTemplate().flush();
      return entity;
  }
```

Configuration: Spring

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd">

    <!-- Hibernate SessionFactory -->
    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
         <list>
                 <value>com.mycompany.TestEntity</value>

         </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.query.substitutions">true 'Y', false 'N'</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.default_schema">MYSCHEMA</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.isolation">1</prop>
                 <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <!-- Create/update the database tables automatically when the JVM starts up
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop> -->
                <!-- Turn batching off for better error messages under PostgreSQL
                <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">0</prop> -->
                <prop key="hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>                               
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</prop>                        
                                <prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider</prop>
                                </props>
                                </property>
    </bean>
  </beans>
```

Comment: how does `update()` is called when do you need a row inserted? suppose you share the configurations of the project and it may be helpful.

Comment: Added additional configurations as requested.